# Redirect to the same page (without PHP)

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that can be called from any page. It opens on top of the current page with z-index. I cannot use php in this case. The form is send to a cgi to process the values. It is necessary to put something in "redirect" if I leave it blank it don't works. In redirect is there a way to put the value to the current page whatever it is?

```
<Form id="formulari" method="POST" action="http://cgi.domain.com/FormMail.pl">
<p>
  <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@domain">
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="IB4 correu">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="TheSamePageWeAre">  
</p>

<form>
<input type="text" name="name" value="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this javascript at the end of the page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.getElementsByName('redirect')[0].value = window.location.pathname;
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do I put in the value of the redirect? I need to put something, if not I get an error. On the other site, if I get a solution to this I was thinking to have just 1 file with the form and call it in every page of my web with jQuery. So Where should I put your code?

Comment: you should put the script code at the end of the file in which you'll define your cgi form.

Comment: I leave the value of redirect empty and I put your code at the end I cannot make it work: http://jsbin.com/iqodor/1/edit I must be doing something wrong. Is there an equivalent with jQuery perhaps it's easier?

Answer (score 0):

Set an `id` on the hidden field, for example `id="redirect"`, and use this Javascript:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function (){
    document.getElementById('redirect').value = location
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I leave the value of redirect empty, I added the id="redirect" and I added your code to the head and it works perfect. Thank you so much!! Jus for curiosity is there an equivalent of your code in jQuery? Something like: $("#redirect").value = location;

Comment: Yes, that will work, and you can put it in `document.ready` instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: Your option with Javascrpt works perfect. My adaptation to jQuery doen't: $(function(){$("#redirect").value = location;})

Comment: You'd need to use `val()` instead of `.value`.